# How to use scipy's dijkstra function in special matrix?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, scipy, dijkstra

I have some code that let's me transform an unweighed graph into a weighed one, where some nodes have weights 1 and some have weights 0. The final result is a matrix. I would like to know how to use this matrix with the Djikstra scipy implementation but don't fully understand the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra.html) and there are not a lot of begginer friendly resources around it so I am not sure what to do. Here is the implementation of the djikstra code from the library

```
def dijkstra_algorithm(matrix, s_id, t_id):
    scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra(matrix)
```

And here is the code for the creation of the matrix with weights and no weights

```
def read_special_graph():
    node_ids = {}

    counter = 0
    for node in nodes:
        node_ids[node] = counter
        counter += 1

    matrix = [[float("inf")]*len(nodes) for _ in range(len(nodes))]

    s_id = node_ids[s.id]
    t_id = node_ids[t.id]
    for node in nodes:
        node_id = node_ids[node.id]
        for out_node in node.out_edges:
            out_id = node_ids[out_node.id]
            if out_node.red:   
                matrix[node_id][out_id] = 1
            else:   
                matrix[node_id][out_id] = 0
    
    dijkstra_algorithm(matrix, s_id, t_id)
```

I don't have an error message since I havent ran it yet, I'm just not aware of what I am supposed to do with my case.

I have written different code for parsing some files where the nodes come from.

Answer (score 0):

That function will compute the full distance matrix, so you can get your distance with

```
def dijkstra_algorithm(matrix, s_id, t_id):
    transitive_matrix = scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra(matrix)
    return transitive_matrix[s_id, t_id]
```

It mentions the dijkstra algorithm with Fibonacci heaps (python heapq I assume), so I imagine you could compute this faster using other methods.